# Bucket created by EBS (Elastic Beanstalk) cannot be deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried the Elastic Beanstalk(EBS) to practice my learning and quickly I deleted it. However, I see there is an S3 bucket created by this EBS service during its launch, is still existing though everything else (like Ec2) is deleted on its on while I deleted the EBS in my account. I want to delete this S3 too, but it gives error while deleting: **"Insufficient permissions to delete bucket" After you or your AWS admin have updated your IAM permissions to allow s3:DeleteBucket, choose delete bucket. API response -Access Denied**

I created EBS and deleted under my root account. I am still under my root account while trying to delete S3 but I get this error. Can someone pls advise, what I am missing here because I did not used any S3 Role as it points in its error message. Any help pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the S3 dashboard, select the bucket you want to delete
2. Select the "Permissions" tab.
3. Navigate to the Bucket Policies & delete the policy

It is the bucket policy created by EB that denies its deletion.

Once the policy is deleted, you will be able to delete the bucket as well.

Comment: Thanks! Though I deleted the Roles, but could not help. Hence I modified the existing policy itself which allowed me to delete it. Thanks for the hint. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**

- To delete the bucket created by Beanstalk we need to modify the attached bucket policy created by beanstalk as it denies the delete action.
- To allow the delete action we can either modify the policy and allow
  the delete action or the easy way is to directly delete/remove the
  policy.
- If you want to delete the policy using python code you can check the
  example given below.

*Note: The below python code will delete all the buckets from your account. You can modify the code if you want to delete any specific bucket. You can download the credentials needed from the IAM service*

`import boto3`

```
   # authenticate s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
       aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY',
       aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_ACCESS',
                      )
   
   bucket = 'bucket_name'

   # delete policy if bucket is created by beanstalk
   bucket.Policy().delete()

   # delete object versions
   bucket.object_versions.delete()

   # delete all the objects inside the bucket
   bucket.objects.all().delete()

   # delete the bucket
   bucket.delete()
   print(bucket, ' deleted successfully!')
```